# JFrame not properly sized

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

If I set the size of `JPanel` first, then set the panel to be the content pane of an unsized frame, the frame will be squeezed into a very small rectangle in the top-left corner of the screen.

But if I set the size of frame first and then set the panel to be its content pane the frame will be properly drawn.

Why does this happen and how do I solve this if I really want to specify the size of `JPanel` rather than `JFrame`?

Comment: What layout managers you you using?  Setting a components "size" via the `setSize` method will be overridden by the layout managers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should tell the frame to pack itself when it is first shown:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This will cause the frame to adopt a size that suits its contents.

Comment: This will cause the frame to adopt a size that suits *its contents' preferable sizes*.